# Were there any kind of 'fictional' prosaic or dramatic works in ancient Israel?

Tags: history-of-literature, hebrew-language

From what I know, the main form of 'art' in ancient Israel was musical - singing, dancing and playing instruments. This was very widespread back then, even extending to many biblical promises about life on the new Earth. Literature, however *(apart from the Bible of course, but I definitely wouldn't consider the Bible or even any deuterocanonical or apocryphal works, such as the Book of Enoch, to be 'fictional' in any way)*, especially prose and drama, seems to be almost unheard of in Hebrew society. I know only one example of a Jewish dramatist *(Ezekiel of Alexandria)*, and no example of an ancient Hebrew novel writer. For this reason, I'm curious about whether the art of writing 'fictional' prosaic stories existed in ancient Israel, or on the contrary, if this was discouraged or even considered sinful *(such as breaking the Second Commandment about idolatry)*.

Comment: The Book of Job is arguably a parable rather than a history, i.e., a work of fiction.

Comment: We don't know how _literally_ true many  of the Old Testament stories are; that isn't the point of them.

Comment: You could consider the parable that Nathan tells to King David of the rich man who kills the poor man's beloved sheep as a form of oral fiction.

Comment: Not sure if this is quite what you are looking for, but the Talmud records that [Rabbi Meir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Meir?wprov=sfti1) had 300 fox parables (of which only three were preserved).